# Derivatives of the limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, sequence-of-function

I would like to show the following result

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions $C^{1}$ of an interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with real or complex values. We suppose that we have the following two conditions

The sequence of derivatives $(f_{n}^{'})_n$ converges uniformly to a function $g$ on $I$.

There exists $x_0\in I$ such that the numerical sequence $(f_n(x_0))_n$ converges to a limit $l$.

Then the sequence $(f_n)_n$ simply converges on $I$ to a function $f$ which is $C^{1}$ and verifies $f'=g$.

What I have tried :
We have for all $x\in I$:

$f_n(x)=f_n(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x}f_{n}^{'}(t)dt$

Then we apply the theorem that allows to invert limit and integral when we have uniform convergence:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_0)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x_0}^{x}f_{n}^{'}(t)dt=l+\int_{x_0}^{x}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}^{'}(t)dt=l+\int_{x_0}^{x}g(t)dt$

and we notice then, using the continuity of $g(t)$ and posing $d'(t)=g(t)$, that

$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x_0}^{x}g(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}[d(x)-d(x_0)]=g(x)$

Do you think it is correct ?

Comment: Yes, correct if (in case $I$ is unbounded) you temporarily restrict to *any* bounded subinterval. Note also that your 2 last lines can be abridged (no need for $d$, just invoke the fundamental theorem of calculus to say that $f'=g$). For a generalization (in french) : [Théorème de différentiation terme à terme](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Calcul_diff%C3%A9rentiel/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_utiles#Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_diff%C3%A9rentiation_terme_%C3%A0_terme).

Comment: Hello ! You clearly answer my question, thank you very much! The generalization is a bit more difficult aha but I'll take the time to think about it to understand it, I didn't do much topology so I miss some notions (I'm French so the article is very useful yes)